# Google Play Console's Data Safety section - Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Here's a question asked in Google Play Console's Data Safety section:

Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected?

Two options are given:

- Data collection is required (users can't turn off this data collection)
- Users can choose whether this data is collected

I'm trying to figure out what option should be chosen for this question. For more context, my app doesn't necessarily give users the option to "turn off this data collection" but they do still have the option to choose whether this data is collected. How? Because they can log in as a guest and not provide any email addresses or User IDs. So it's completely up to them whether they want this data type to be collected. But if they do sign up with an email address or User ID, they don't have the option to turn off that data from being collected unless they delete their account.

So which option should I be choosing for my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't have a choice to turn it off, then data collection is required.  Being in a guest account doesn't actually protect any privacy.